# Filtering a List .NET C# - best performance - strange results

Tags: c#, performance, linq, collections, .net-5

so I am trying to filter a list in c# .NET5 and I would like to focus on the performance of the process. Currently the Program is using a ForEach loop for that, which is terrible.

Anyways this is the example, I get a list of strings, which can contain any kind of strings, including null or empty. With 10k entries.

I found filtering methods using LINQ, e.g. .Where or .RemoveAll, however you like to filter.

First I thought the best and fastest way would be to make a hashset and use List.RemoveAll(i => hashset.Contains(i))
because all my researches were pointing out the iterating a List using hashset.Contains is the fastest method. Also I thought RemoveAll would be faster, because the checking of Contains-Method can stop as soon it returns one "true" case.

I made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvmWHk) to benchmark all of these methods, but the thing is, I got these results:

```
.Where & HashSet contains: 0.7018 MS
.RemoveAll & HashSet contains: 0.4803 MS
.Where & List contains: 0.0072 MS
.RemoveAll & List contains: 0.4504 MS
.Where 0.1234 MS
.RemoveAll 0.0006 MS
ForEach 41.8379 MS
```

These results brought new questions up and hopefully I could get an explanation or just a clear answer.

The questions:

1. As expected .RemoveAll & HashSet was faster than .Where & HashSet, but this didn't apply for List.Contains, why?
2. Why are the results via List.Contains faster than both HashSet methods? especially .Where & List
3. Why is the normal List.Where, which always checks if 4 statements are true faster than both HashSet methods?
4. I expected that List.RemoveAll would be fast, but I didn't expect it to be that fast... Most of my searches and questions I looked up, people always suggested to use a HashSet for such a case.

I hope somebody could explain, at least some of it.

**EDIT:**

I figured out, the last .RemoveAll method was a mistake I did, I used .Where instead of .RemoveAll, now things are becoming a bit clearer. I also removed the .ToLower funtions in the ForEach loop

Now I get these results:

```
.Where & HashSet contains: 0.6769 MS
.RemoveAll & HashSet contains: 0.4603 MS
.Where & List contains: 0.0052 MS
.RemoveAll & List contains: 0.449 MS
.Where 0.1103 MS
.RemoveAll 0.305 MS
ForEach 0.4445 MS
```

But I still ask, why is the HashSet taking longer than the List while using .Where.
And also why is RemoveAll faster than Where while using a HashSet, but the opposite happens with List?

Comment: _Materialize_ those lists. Most LINQ functions are NOT evaluated until you actually enumerate their result. With that said: to setup a microbenchmark is a bit more complicate than this (at the very least you must repeat each test a thousands time and then average - after removing outliers)

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. `RemoveAll` actually modifies the current list while `Where & List contains` does nothing but creating a query. Append `ToList` and assign it to the original list and you can compare the result(but still it's different since you've created a new list).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for your answer. But wouldn't it make sense, that RemoveAll & List/HashSet Contains should take longer than Where & List/HashSet Contains, or the opposite? because right now I have both scenarios, which made me confused a bit.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for telling me that. Honestly I didn't know about the materialization. I would gladly take a look into it and try to do so. Once I am done, I might share my result here and I would be happy to get an answer from you.

Comment: Also use BenchmarkDotnet, not a fiddle for more reliable numbers.

Comment: @MrJami; Why you have both scenarios? The second where you output `".RemoveAll"` is not using `RemoveAll` at all. Instead you are using again `Enumerable.Where` which is using deferred execution, so not actually removing anything. Btw, don't use `value.ToLower() != "alle"` but `"alle.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)"` which is one reason for the slow foreach loop. Also initialize the result-list with the same size as the input list: `var returnValues = new List<string>(input.Count)`

Comment: Also, `RemoveAll` alters the `input` list, so all subsequent tests are garbage

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for pointing that out. I didnt see that somehow.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you again for pointing that out. Might you please check the question again, I added a paragraph below "Edit"

Comment: @MrJami: "But I still ask, why is the HashSet taking longer than the List while using .Where" See my [comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303839/filtering-a-list-net-c-sharp-best-performance-strange-results?noredirect=1#comment120717716_68304062). A HashSet becomes faster the more items it contains. There's an overhead for the hashcode search, if it just contains few items a list/array-contains with "brute-force" search is faster.

Comment: @TimSchmelter got that, thank you. Now only the last question remains :)

Comment: @MrJami: the last question about Where with List and HashSet? The time is nearly same, you can't draw any conclusions about that, also you should use BenchmarkDotNet instead of these naive comparisons. 
1)`.RemoveAll & HashSet contains: 0.4521 MS`
2)`.RemoveAll & List contains: 0.4433 MS`

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, I didnt mean that. I mean why is RemoveAll faster than Where while using a HashSet, but the **opposite** happens with List?

Comment: @MrJami: Can you say what console outputs you are comparing in your benchmark code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter .Where & List contains: 0.0052 MS < .RemoveAll & List contains: 0.449 MS **&** .Where & HashSet contains: 0.6769 MS > .RemoveAll & HashSet contains: 0.4603 MS

Comment: You can't compare the `Where` with `RemoveAll` at all since `Where` is using deferred execution, so it's just creating a query and not a list(append `ToList` to get a meaningful result). So the final question is why `Where(HashSet.Contains)` appears to be "much" slower than `Where(List.Contains)`. That's why i've said you should use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html). Reverse both tests and suddenly the `List.Contains` will be slower. You need a warmup for your benchmarks. Anyway, these `Where` tests are worthless without a `ToList`.

Comment: Also in the first call to `RemoveAll` you remove ~5.500 elements from the list `input`. The later calls only operate on ~4.500 elements, the first two on 10.000 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tests are misleading, to my point of view.
You have more expensive comparisons in the for each loop (2x ToLower) and and also in most of Linq-statements you don't even execute the query (They rest in a deferred/unexecuted state).

The reason for the list beating the hashset in this scenario is that they both contain just a few elements (5) and also the list you compare against will contain only 5 different values.
So most of the time you call List.Contains you will have less than 3 iterations - this are less steps to go than in the hashet in this scenario where you have at least an additional call to GetHashCode for each element.

If I refactor your test, ForEach beats Where by roughly 1 to 10%.
If I change the count of distinct elements, HashSet beats List by far (5x as fast)!
I didn't use RemoveAll, because its a different operation.

```
/*

Result of Benchmark.RunAllTests():

Test 'where hashset' took 42,71700 msec
Test 'where list' took 285,44390 msec
Test 'foreach hashset' took 41,99030 msec
Test 'foreach list' took 277,24130 msec

*/
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Benchmark
    {
        Random _random = new Random();

        public void RunAllTests() {

            var hs = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => _random.Next(0, i).ToString()).ToHashSet();
            var ls    = new List<string>(hs);

            var bigList = FillList(1_000_000, ls);

            //warmup, let all assemblies load
            RunTest(() => bigList.Take(100).Where(s => !hs.Contains(s)).ToList(), "", true);
            RunTest(() => bigList.Take(100).Where(s => !ls.Contains(s)).ToList(), "", true);
            //exec real tests
            RunTest(() => bigList.Where(s => !hs.Contains(s)).ToList(), "where hashset");
            RunTest(() => bigList.Where(s => !ls.Contains(s)).ToList(), "where list");
            RunTest(() => ForEach(hs).ToList(),                         "foreach hashset");
            RunTest(() => ForEach(ls).ToList(),                         "foreach list");

            IEnumerable<string> ForEach(ICollection<string> coll) {
                foreach (var s in bigList) {
                    if (!coll.Contains(s))
                        yield return s;
                }
            }
        }

        private List<string> FillList(int totalCount, IList<string> elementsToUse)
        {
            var input = new List<string>();
            
            for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
            {
                var n = _random.Next(0, elementsToUse.Count);
                input.Add(elementsToUse[n]);
            }

            return input;
        }

        private void RunTest(Func<IList<string>> test, string name, bool silent = false) {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            var list = test.Invoke();

            if (silent) {
                return;
            }
            var ms = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test '{0:-20}' took {1:N5} msec", name, ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are comparing completely wrong numbers here.

1. Where doesn't do anything, really. It creates an `IEnumerable` instance that will call into the filter function when required, i.e. when the collection is iterated. Because your fiddle does not iterate the collection, the filter predicate is never actually executed.
2. `RemoveAll` and the foreach implementation also means comparing apples and oranges because your foreach implementation uses `ToLower`, a function that is suprisingly expensive. Remove the `ToLower` method call and foreach is the fastest. In particular, adding items to a List is roughly O(1) while removing an item from a list is O(n), so it is clear that `RemoveAll` is slower than foreach.
3. I believe foreach on a list will still create an instance of the enumerator. You can omit that by using a `for`-loop. That will be "faster" by an amount that will for sure not solve any problem.
4. Why are you even asking? 10k items is really not that much. I'd rather concentrate on getting the filter predicate right instead of thinking about how to call that. The differences will be negligible unless you really have high-performance needs.

Comment: But doesn't this mean that creating an IEnumerable instance, should be the fastest? Also thank you for pointing out the .ToLower function. _"it is clear that RemoveAll is slower than foreach."_ I removed it and tried the "benchmark" 15-20 and RemoveAll is still the fastest method. And also I am asking, because I wanted to learn and I didn't find an explanation for this on the net. Thanks for your contribution btw ^^

Comment: It''s worth noting that also the HashSet is not really helpful here. It's more efficient if it was large, but with few items in it a plain list or array would be faster. Also note that a `HashSet<T>` takes an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__), so you can pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to make it more efficient if you want to ignore the case anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Alright, so far I understood almost everything. But still I dont get why if I use HashSet I get .Where slower than .RemoveAll and if I use List I get .Where faster than .RemoveAll

Comment: You need to refill the list for each test.
In your 1st test you have 10.000 elements.
Then after the first call to RemoveAll you remove 5.500 of them (all that do not equal "good");